# Docker Desktop Kubernetes Windows PV Non Root Container

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bitnami

I'm trying to get Wordpress running with a shared volume for `wp-config.php` across replicas. I'm developing my manifest on Docker Desktop for Windows on top of the Ubuntu WSL v2. I've enabled the Kubernetes functionality of Docker Desktop, which seems to be working fine with the exception of `PersistentVolume` resx's. Here are the relevant snippets from my manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0
  namespace: yuknis-com
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /c/Users/Kirkland/pv0
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - "docker-desktop"
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: pvc0
  name: wordpress-pvc
  namespace: yuknis-com
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 60Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  namespace: yuknis-com
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress-pvc
      initContainers:
      - name: volume-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'chmod -R g+rwX /bitnami']
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami
          name: wordpress
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: yuknis/wordpress-nginx-phpredis:latest
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef: 
            name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress
          mountPath: /bitnami
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
```

When I try to run my application on MacOS, it works fine with the above. However when I try to run it on Windows, it fails on the `initContainer` portion with an error of:

```
chmod: /bitnami: Operation not permitted
chmod: /bitnami: Operation not permitted
```

Why might this work on MacOS, but not on Windows on top of the WSL? Any ideas?

Comment: ReadWriteMany volumes are hard to get in many environments, and in general it's hard to edit a PersistentVolume from outside the cluster.  If it's storing your application configuration, would injecting it via a ConfigMap be a better choice?  You shouldn't need the initContainer running `chmod`; the mounted ConfigMap volume should be world-readable.

Comment: I can understand from the in a nutshell book for kube it's not recommended, however the secret hashes portion of the Wordpress config is statefull, and needs to be shared once generated across pods so it might be necessary. I don't believe the manifest attempts to modify the volume outside of the cluster, as it is being done by an initContainer which I believe does execute as a pod. And the reason why I need to chmod the volume is because Bitnami containers run as a non-root user, and Kube mounts volumes as root.

Comment: Also, I did just try running it with a single replica as a ReadWriteOnce volume, the same issue exists. I then tried to remove the initContainer with ReadWriteOnce set and Wordpress came back with `mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/wordpress': Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7023). Docker Desktop has its own WSL distribution, so you can't access it from the same root.

Workaround for this issue is to change path in your PV:

```
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: hostpath
  local:
    path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/Kirkland/pv0
```

Check the github post I linked for considerations using this method.

Comment: I have to try after work, I'll be able to answer then. I apologize for the delay. It is worth noting that I tried something along the lines of this, however I used `/mnt/c/...` and not `/run/desktop/...` and that diddn't work. Might I ask where `/run/desktop` comes from?

Comment: It's how Windows directories are mounted in WSL, check issue I linked for more details

Comment: It worked, thanks! While I was still confused about why the different path to the `C:` drive, I switched the default WSL to `docker-desktop` with `wsl --set-default docker-desktop` then started the wsl shell. As that point I was able to see the different directory structure when compared to Ubuntu on WSL. Thanks again!